# Output SQL Delta Script

Tags: flyway

Does the latest release allow flyway to save all the migration SQLs in a delta script instead of running them in the database?  It's a useful feature a lot of other tools have (liquibase, dbdeploy, etc.).

It's pefectly fine to have a tool automatically apply changes in non-production databases, but I would like to have more control in the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

**No, it doesn't.** It also wouldn't be as relevant as for other tools, as the **input format** (SQL with optional placeholders) is **very similar to the output format** (SQL without placeholders).

To know what will happen you also have **flyway.info()** which also displays **pending migrations**.

You can also use **flyway.target** to control up to which migration the process should run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Axel.  That should work in most circumstances.  However, some companies may require that scripts be handed to a release engineer to run in production.  So it would be nice if we have the option to simply redirect all the SQLs to a delta script.

Are all the features supported by the commandline tool?